# Tkinter and Python - variable type error and how to overwrite strings - Reaction Time Test

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a reaction test working in the console, but I was curious about making a desktop app out of it so I decided to check out Tkinter, but I'm having some conversion and functionality issues. 
Firstly, for the countdown, can Tkinter overwrite strings to produce an effect of a countdown (3,2,1,GO).
Secondly, I'm not sure how to make the 'start' variable a float so that it can be subtracted to give the value for the 'elapsed' variable.
I feel like I'm really close. Just missing something.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import time, random

root = Tk()

content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3,3,12,12), width=500, height=100)

def callback():
    elapsed = time.time()- start
    print(elapsed)
    result.set(elapsed)

result = StringVar()

def countdown():    
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,6))
    d = '!__GO__!'
    cd.set(d)
    start = time.time()
    start.set(start)

start = StringVar()
cd = StringVar()

ttk.Button(content, text="Start", command=countdown).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=NW)
ttk.Label(content, text="Click on GO!").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Button(content, text="Go", command = callback).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(content, text="Result is: ").grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(E,W))
ttk.Label(content, textvariable=cd).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=S)
ttk.Label(content, textvariable=result).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=S)
```

I'd like the countdown to display 3, then 2 to overwrite it, then 1, then GO.
And then for the elapsed time to be shown from when the Start button is pressed and when the Go button is pressed (ie. elapsed = time.time() - start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep` will block your main thread such that your program will freeze for the duration of `time.sleep`. You need to either `thread` your function, or use the `after` method available for tkinter which allows you to fire a callback after certain time.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
import random

root = Tk()

content = ttk.Frame(root, padding=(3,3,12,12), width=500, height=100)
content.pack()

def callback():
    global start_time
    elapsed = datetime.now() - start_time
    result.set(elapsed)

result = StringVar()

def start(): #generates random countdown timer
    t = random.randint(2,6)
    def countdown(num): #function to provide countdown effect
        start_var.set(num)
        if num >=1:
            num -= 1
            root.after(1000,lambda: countdown(num)) #call itself again until countdown reaches 0
        else:
            start_var.set("GO!")
            global start_time
            start_time = datetime.now()
    countdown(t)

start_var = StringVar()

ttk.Button(content, text="Start", command=start).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=NW)
ttk.Label(content, text="Click on GO!").grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=N)
ttk.Button(content, text="Go", command=callback).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=N)
ttk.Label(content, text="Result is: ").grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(E,W))
ttk.Label(content, textvariable=start_var).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=S)
ttk.Label(content, textvariable=result).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=S)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the info. I'm still very new to tkinter so don't know these methods. I was wanting the GO to appear at a random time after 1, instead of the countdown being a random time though.  So hopefully the after method will do what I need it to do